# jplayer duration and process not work on chrome

Tags: tomcat, jplayer

i used jplayer on other browser,it works fine,on chrome,everything can works fine,but the duration and progress can'work,the server used Tomcat,the is the console[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65bw0.png)

Comment: Your server needs to respond with partial requests enabled otherwise progress bar and stuff won't work in chrome. [Link](https://www.google.de/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_en-GBDE765DE765&ei=FjoUWsDNFJCykwWTvKmoBw&q=chrome+audio+partial+content&oq=chrome+audio+partial+content&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30k1l2.7188.8014.0.8092.8.8.0.0.0.0.164.424.3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.3.349....0.k1NDHnwLhE0)

Comment: tomcat can't support this?

Comment: I have no idea about tomcat

Answer (score 0):

If it is not too late... I checked my mp3 on Chrome, Yours is mainly different from mine in 3 points:

1. Yours - Status Code : 200 OK ; Mine - Status Code : 206 Partial Content
2. Yours - (Content-Length missing) ; Mine - Content-Length: 4975034
3. Yours - (Content-Range missing) ; Mine - Content-Range:bytes 0-4975033/4975034

You should check the Content-Length and/or Content-Range is generated from your Tomcat Server. I don't know Tomcat, I heard there was a bug from providing Content-Length but it was fixed according to this [Tomcat Post](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Adding-Content-Length-response-header-td4996989.html).

I don't know why only Chrome does not see the Content-Length, or maybe the other Browsers are reading its length by downloading the whole file first before making available to JPlayer.

YOUR MP3 IS BEING SERVED FROM DISK FILE SYSTEM, meaning that you have no control on setting programmatically the Content-Length to the response. So The only thing you can do is to configure Tomcast Server or modify options to have it return the Content-Length in file.

But here is my mp3 header result on Chrome localhost:

```
General --->
Request URL:http://localhost/songs/album/album_1085/song_Ma%20Cherie%20Je%20T'aime_1425654205.mp3
Request Method:GET
Status Code:206 Partial Content
Remote Address:[::1]:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers --->
view source
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=7776000
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:4975034
Content-Range:bytes 0-4975033/4975034
Content-Type:audio/mpeg
Date:Wed, 27 Dec 2017 17:24:22 GMT
ETag:"4be9ba-560a79f00fbc0"
Expires:Tue, 27 Mar 2018 17:24:22 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Tue, 19 Dec 2017 01:45:27 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.28 (Unix) PHP/5.6.31

Request Headers --->
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:remember_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc=eyJpdiI6...(skipped); XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6...(skipped)
Host:localhost
Pragma:no-cache
Range:bytes=0-
Referer:http://localhost/song/Ma+Cherie+Je+T%27aime.54451502
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
```